# Changing the price format not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a price string which contains a data like this

```
 22,95
```

This price is in danish format, integers seperated by comma. I want to convert this in to universal format. means I want an out put like this

```
22.95
```

I have tried some thing like this

```
public static string getFormattedPrice(string value)
{
    double moneyValue;
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo english = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
    Double.TryParse(value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, english, out moneyValue);
    return value;
}
```

But the result is still

```
 22,95
```

Any one know what is the correct way to implement this.
Note:please don't tell me I can make string replace, where all comma can be replaced with a dot.As this is a business critical data and I want to go with correct way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should use `decimal` instead of `double` to represent financial data.

Then, you're trying to parse your string using `en-GB` format, but as your said it's `da-DK`. Instead of parsing data using English culture info you should use it after parsing, to get new string.

And what even more important, you're returning exactly the same value that was passes as method parameter. Why do you expect it to work?

This one works as expected:

```
public static string getFormattedPrice(string value)
{
    decimal moneyValue;
    var danish = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("da-DK");
    decimal.TryParse(value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, danish, out moneyValue);
    return moneyValue.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Comment: This code works fine in my local system.But when it goes to production server it is not.Server is in danish culture. does it have anything to do with it?

Comment: It means the string you're passing into method is not formated using danish format. Because culture info instances on all parse/tostring methods within the method are set, the behavior does not vary depending on system settings.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple way

```
decimal dollarAmount = 123165.4539M;
string text = dollarAmount.ToString("C",Cultures.US);

Console.WriteLine(text);


public static class Cultures
{
    public static readonly CultureInfo US= 
        CultureInfo.ReadOnly(new CultureInfo("en-US"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
public static string getFormattedPrice(string value)
{
double moneyValue ;
System.Globalization.CultureInfo english = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
Double.TryParse(value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, english, out moneyValue);
return moneyValue.toString();
}
```

Comment: It does not even compile. *Cannot implicitly convert type '`double`' to '`string`'*